# iPhone - UITableviewcell label movement when press Editing

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In the normal behavior when Edit is pressed, the red delete circles appear from the left. This shifts the entire cell to the left.
When this happens, custom labels on the far right of the cell overlap the cell movement touch area.

The solution is to move custom UILabels to the left when edit is pressed.

How is this done?

[image: example cell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `UILabel` is being added to the `contentView` of your cell, just make sure your subviews (whether a `UILabel` or other `UIView`-derived object) have their `autoresizingMask` set up to allow flexible width (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`). Also, your left subviews need `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`, while your right subviews should have `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`.

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen this property before. What I used was label.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);